# Estimating expectation from a Markov chain process with AR(1) framework and stochastic volatility

Tags: volatility, models, price, stochastic, markov

I have a stochastic volatility model of a commodity price as follows:

```
ln(pt ) − m = ρ (ln(pt−1) − m) + exp(σt)ut    ut ∼ IID(0, 1)
σt − μ = ρσ(σt−1 − μ) + ηεt       εt ∼ IID(0, 1)
```

Can anyone help me estimate the expectation of the price which follows a Markov chain process? I have estimated the parameters and also have the transition probabilities for both the volatility ($\sigma$) and the ln(price). In my model both of these have 7 states in the grid. I want to see how the expectation of price varies with different levels of price level and volatility state.